# Monitoring NebulaGraph K8s resources

Tags: nebula-graph

We want to extend our existing monitoring to include Nebula resources such as node, service and space.
How can we do this, can you please point me to any documentation

Answer (score 0):

- For node, I take it as the OS/Machine level, the vanilla node exporter(and Prometheus)[0] will do the job.
- For Service/Space level monitoring, we could leverage the nebula-stats-operator[1]

And actually, there is an all-in-one solution out there in the NebulaGraph community called NebulaGraph Dashboard[2], in which it wired everything together already, even if you are connecting things from scratch on your own, you could still refer to it(on how it leveraged the exporters).

For documentation, you could check the following chapters:

- dashboard https://docs.nebula-graph.io/3.3.0/nebula-dashboard/1.what-is-dashboard/
- metrics https://docs.nebula-graph.io/3.3.0/6.monitor-and-metrics/1.query-performance-metrics/

ref:

- [0] https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter
- [1] https://github.com/vesoft-inc/nebula-stats-exporter
- [2] https://github.com/vesoft-inc/nebula-dashboard